# carts_prod_id_foreign

Tags: php, laravel

I want To Make The Prod_id A Forgin Key So I Can Add to Cart And get The Id Of Product

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table`ecommerce1`.`carts`(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table`carts`add constraint`carts_prod_id_foreign `foreign key (`prod_id`) references` products `(`id`) on delete cascade)
at

This Is The Table Migration

```
 Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->BigInteger('prod_id');
        $table->string('prod_qty');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('carts', function($table)
    {
        $table->foreign('prod_id')
        ->references('id')->on('products')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide real code and not images, then, I guess you have some errors in your routes, provide the content of your routes to check

Comment: can you show your route definition that is using a resource? `Route::resource` or `Route::apiResource`

Answer (score 0):

Your definition for the `product` resource is incorrect. You should adjust it to passing a string as the second argument:

```
Route::resource('product', App\Http\Controllers\User\indexController::class);
```

The second argument to `resource` is a string, which is the Controller. There is no method specified as resources are particular things which define individual routes with actions to multiple methods of that particular controller.

Though, you already have `profile` using this Controller and defined as a resource so not sure the reason to then have the same routes but as the `product` resource.

Perhaps you meant to just create a `GET` route for that one method?:

```
Route::get('product', [App\Http\Controllers\User\indexController::class, 'product'])->name('product');
```